# C++ Memory leak fix

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I was asked to optimize c++ project and there i've faced this "memory leak" situation inside class code (example simplified but main problem is clear):

```c
std::list<T*> _list;
void func(){
    T* obj = some_func();
    if (!obj){
        obj = new T();
        _list.push_back(obj); // Here is a leak,we do not know when *obj will be removed from _list to call its destructor 
    }
    obj->some_field = some_value; 
}
/*_list will be used and managed somewhere else 
  and we do not know actually when, where and how.*/
```

So how this can be fixed the elegantly? By elegantly I mean without defining my own container.
Do I need to use some smart pointers?

**UPDATE. This is not C++ 11. So no fancy useful stuff**

Comment: How did you manage to push a `T*` into a list of `T`? Does `T` have a constructor that takes a `T*`?

Comment: have you actually observed a memory leak ? This code is reasonable if the list takes ownership of the object.

Comment: I don't think the main problem is clear at all. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: First make your example compile. Then we can think about the problem.

Comment: Well, the code above is problematic as it violates the RAII idiom, opening exception safety issues if, for some reason, push_back should throw. But the main problem I see is that resource ownership seems to be unclear.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry, there should be a list<T*>.

Comment: You can use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker  Intel Inspector XE shown this as a actual leak. I believe it =)

Comment: @SebastianRedl i've updated question. It should be `list<T*>`.

Comment: @Seter: Better yet; `list<T>` or `list<unique_ptr<T>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how this can be fixed the elegantly?

Store objects if possible, or smart pointers otherwise. Memory management through dumb pointers is a recipe for memory leaks and worse.

`std::unique_ptr` would be the best smart pointer - it matches the semantics of a single owner (the list), with the ability to transfer ownership in and out. However, you say you're stuck in the past, so the best available option is probably `shared_ptr` from TR1 or Boost.

> Do I need to use some smart pointers?

It's by far the easiest solution, assuming you can't store objects. The alternative is to carefully control how pointers are removed from the list, making sure you either delete them or transfer ownership in a well-specified way (and that the new owner discharges its responsibilities correctly). You would essentially be defining your own container adapter; although you could use a ready-made solution like Boost's pointer containers.

Answer (score 0):

What is the protocol for using some_func?  Is the caller supposed to take ownership of the returned object?  If so, it would be leaked.  You need to push the obj returned by some_func onto the list, assuming the list takes ownership of the object.  Indeed, using unique_ptrs here would help make this more clear.

Comment: hm,but what if *obj returned by some_func is null? We can't push it inide _list. So the main problem appears when we create new instance of T with "new" and  pushing it inside some global _list and we do not know when it will be removed from _list (in my opinion this actually cause memory leak)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are storing pointers to your list (`std::list<T*> _list;`), perhaps this could help:

```
namespace RAII
{
    template<typename T>
    class AUTO_LIST_WITH_POINTER
    {
    public:
        AUTO_LIST_WITH_POINTER(){}
        ~AUTO_LIST_WITH_POINTER()
        {
            // if you compiler does not support lambdas, replace this with
            // a simple 'for' loop
            std::for_each( list_.begin(), list_.end(), []( T * & listItem )throw()
            {
                delete listItem;
            } );
        }

        const std::list<T*> & get()const
        {
            return list_;
        }

        std::list<T*> & get()
        {
            return list_;
        }

        std::list<T*> detach() // Warning: probably an expensive operation!!!!
        {
            std::list<T*> list( list_ );
            list_.clear();
            return list;
        }

    private:
        std::list<T*> list_;

        AUTO_LIST_WITH_POINTER( const AUTO_LIST_WITH_POINTER & );             // TODO: don't implement, or..?? the OP should know better
        AUTO_LIST_WITH_POINTER & operator=( const AUTO_LIST_WITH_POINTER & ); // TODO: don't implement, or..?? the OP should know better
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to employ RAII, rely on `std::unique_ptr` along with a move semantics. For example:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>> list;
auto obj = some_func();
int some_value = 1;
if (!obj){
    std::unique_ptr<T> new_obj(new T());
    list.emplace_back(std::move(new_obj));
    obj = list.back().get();
}
obj->some_field = some_value;
```

Comment: It's not C++ 11. So no fancy useful stuff

Comment: @Seter: Then `boost::shared_ptr` will do the same job, albeit with slightly more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Without C++11, you could use `std::auto_ptr<>`. This transfers ownership of the pointer to one single owner, so if `_list` was of type `std::list<std::auto_ptr<T>>`, the objects would be deleted when the container is destroyed.

Comment: Storing `auto_ptr` in a container is a very bad idea. It doesn't meet the CopyConstructible or Assignment requirements for use in standard containers, and it's easy to accidentally copy one out of the container and delete the object.